# Quick movement change of image on swipe scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, pagination, uipagecontrol

In the below code when clicked on page control it moving to another Image, with an quick movement.

Need same effect of quick movement swipe on scroll View.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]init];
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/1.6);
    scrollView.bounces = true;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"]], [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]],[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"]],nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++){
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.scrollView.frame.size.height+10, self.view.frame.size.width,30);
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count;        
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pageControl];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(id)sender {

    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }
}

- (void)changePage:(id)sender{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
}
```

From above code when i click on pageControl its trigger the method **changePage** and move to next page,  same effect need when user swipe from left to right right to left on scrollview.

@All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Add  `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;`  Issue resolved.